# SQL: Possible to use input array in where clause?

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parameterizing an SQL IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause)

Suppose I had a table of schools which school_name, school_enrolment

As input to my program, someone types a list of schools that they would like to see the enrolment for.  Instead of generating an sql query like:

```
SELECT * FROM school_table
WHERE
school_name = 'program_input_1' or school_name = 'program_input_2' or school_name = 'program_input_3'
```

is it possible or straightforward to do something like

```
SELECT * from school_table
WHERE
school name in [array of program inputs]
```

as a much cleaner way of writing this?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, this is what `IN` is for:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM school_table
WHERE school_name IN ('program_input_1', 'program_input_2', 'program_input_3')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `IN(...)` clause:

```
WHERE School_name in ('school 1','school 2')
```

In terms of passing an array, it depends on the programming language you are using to generate the SQL.

You would have to write a custom function that loops over the array, dynamically generating the IN clause